# How to grant access of multiple private git repositories in CI pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to build a new Azure Ruby on Rails pipeline. I have two other ruby private repositories, I need to install these dependency packages for the project. Those two repos are owned by me.

I have added the same SSH Key to my github account as well to my azure devops account. Assuming that this would solve the issue as the error that I am getting says

```
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The repository does exists and I am confused and lost on how to solve this problem. 
I did try to find an option of adding the ssh key as variables in the pipeline but I couldn't find this option. Can someone tell me what is the best way to address this issue.

I have a Gemfile which has

```
gem 'app', git: "https://github.com/organnization/reponame.git",ref:"v1.1"
```

After making the necessary changes mentioned in the comments, using HTTPS instead of SSH I am getting

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

Comment: You'd better, 1) host all private repos on GitHub. 2) use HTTPS links instead of SSH links in your pipeline definition to check out the repo/submodules. Then Azure Pipelines is smart enough to use the same OAuth token to work on all of them. Try not to use SSH, as the configuration of that is rather complicated (what you did is almost of no use).

Comment: @LexLi All of my repos are in github. I tried what you have said, it doesn't work. Any suggestions please. Thank you btw. :)

Comment: Just noticed that you are linking to the repo via gem. Is it possible to 1) add those private repos as submodules to your main repo. 2) configure gem to pick up them from the submodule folders? I don't think gem can reuse the OAuth token the build agent is using. If you do want SSH to work, then you need to pass the SSH keys to the pipeline, similar to what AppVeyor documented https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/private-git-sub-modules/

Comment: Smart, you nailed it Lex Li. Added the private repos as submodules and asked gem to pick up from there. 
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/415783/git-submodule-checkout-fails-on-host-key-verificat.html

This linked also helped me. Thanks :)

Comment: Feel free to post your own answer and accept it. I assume you learned quite a lot from the process that can help others in the future.